# Not able to read description and metadata inside json in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the JSON object like below, in my NODE JS code i am trying to read the description and metadata, but i am getting undefined.

is "description" and "metadata" are reserved key words? if yes how do i process the JSON?

```
{
    "description": "Hello World",
    "metadata" : "Some Value"
}
```

Comment: Is it really Json object? provide some fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here is my example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9hCp9/

Comment: Did you parse the JSON?

Comment: If you are getting it from a string just use JSON.parse(yourJsonString)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "{"description": "Hello World","metadata" : "Some Value"}";
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
alert(obj.description);
```

Comment: It looks incorrect to me: `var result = "{"description": "Hello World","metadata" : "Some Value"}";`. Do you mean: `var result = '{"description": "Hello World","metadata" : "Some Value"}';` (with single quotes at the start and end).